# Case typo on path in msysgit

Tags: windows, git, msysgit

I went out to my github repo and discovered that I had inadvertently added files to msysgit with a typo. Instead of adding files to a directory called "Domain", I added them to "DOmain".

I tried git mv, but the path is case-insensitive in Windows and the move fails.

What's the best way to resolve an issue like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mv` to something else, like "tempdir", and then `mv` back to the proper capitalization?

Comment: I resolved it through a standard mv while inside the typoed directory and right back into the properly typed name:
TYpoedDir$git mv -f file ../GoodDir/file.
Did a git add on the file from the GoodDir and confirmed using git ls-files. All good. Thanks, everyone.

Comment: added add'l comment on ls-files

Answer (score 0):

Go back in history (`git checkout someHash`), create new dir with proper case, checkout the files from the wrong commit (`git checkout someWrongHash someFiles`), commit them, and then, reset HEAD to the new commit.

(And next time, don't torture youreslf with git on Windows ;) )